# How to create a consortium network on geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js

I have a dapp which is build using truffle.i want to create a consortium network and connect that with my truffle dapp? is that possible and how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following step by step tutorial to deploy a Ethereum Consortium based blockchain on Microsoft Azure Platform.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/templates/ethereum-consortium-blockchain-network/

I also recorded a video of it being done,  its about 40mins as I walk through step by step explaining Ethereum along the way.  The actual deployment at the end takes about 12mins from running the script.

[Video Walkthrough Deploying a Ethereum Consortium Blockchain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsConsFaZG8&t=37s)

Comment: tnx you but is there any other way without azure?